# Rails ExtJS- How to build/compile a css file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, extjs, stylesheet

I have a Rails and ExtJS application which has all images under

```
MyApplication/app/assets/graphics
```

The styles are listed in the following file->

```
 MyApplication/app/assets/stylesheets/css/styles.less
```

The following file seems to have a compiled version of all styles

```
MyApplication/app/assets/stylesheets/css/lt.css
```

I added a new image test.png under graphics folder. How can I compile this into the styles? So far, when I refer to this image in my code, it doesn't show up since it is not in the lt.css file.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you found solution? Please check my updated answer. Sorry I didn't see that you have extra css folder. I've just tried in my rails 4 dev. env., and it works. Please let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I didn't see that you have css folder within stylesheet folder.

According to [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the precompile array in `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

SASS & LESS both uses asset helpers `asset-url($relative-asset-path)` except that SASS is equipped with rails by default, so you could use this helper in your `lt.less` or `lt.scss` ( file extension is important )

```
background: image-url('test.png');
```

Just change your `lt.css` to `.less` or `.scss` and the image will show up, and it will be precompiled for you, after using asset helper.

In case that you want to compile to production run this from your terminal before deployment:

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I hope it helps